# If $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$, show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is nonempty

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, alternative-proof

**Question:** If $I_n$ is closed and bounded, $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$, and $I_n\neq\emptyset$, show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is nonempty.

This is not a homework help question. I'm actually looking for a specific proof which does not 1) appeal to the Heine-Borel theorem and 2) use the notions of convergence or sequences.

I recall seeing such a proof before, but I can't remember where.

**Addenda:** We know $I_n\subset\mathbb R^k$. Either we know $I_n$ is compact or that it is closed and bounded, but not both (I forget the exact initial given information, but I'd appreciate a solution from either direction).

Comment: What is $I_n$, an interval in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Actually, I don't entirely remember the conditions. We know either that $I_n$ is compact or that it is closed and bounded, I'm not sure which.

Comment: Oh, right, $I_n$ is in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: With the way you've written the question, we need the Heine-Borel theorem to say that the $I_n$ are compact

Comment: This can be done knowing only it's compact and not that it's closed and bounded, right?

Comment: Let $a_n = \min I_n$. Monotonic, bounded, least upper bound property $\implies$ convergent.

Comment: @DanielFischer: "I'm actually looking for a specific proof which  does not...use the notions of convergence or sequences."

Comment: @user161694: If you assume that the intervals are compact, then you don't need Heine-Borel.  It is relatively easy to show that compact subsets of a metric space are closed and bounded.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm aware, I just don't recall if the proof was using the properties of sets being closed and bounded, or sets being compact.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Ah, parse error. I thought the not applied only to Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is taken from baby Rudin, p. 38. Here, $\{I_n\}$ is a sequence of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

" If $I_n = [a_n, b_n]$, let $E$ be the set of all $a_n$. Then $E$ is nonempty and bounded above (by $b_1$). Let $x$ be the sup of $E$. If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $$a_n \leq a_{m+n} \leq b_{m+n} \leq b_m,$$ so that $x\leq b_m$ for each $m$. Since it is obvious that $a_m\leq x$, we see that $x\in I_m$ for each $m = 1,2,3,\ldots.$"

Comment: This is more or less the proof I saw (except this one is in $R^1$, but there's a trivial extension to $R^k$ by induction).

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a decreasing sequence of sets, we might as well treat the ambient space as $I_1$. So we are in a compact space and we have a decreasing sequence of non-empty closed sets.

But now we remember the following characterization of compactness:

> If $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of closed sets, such that the intersection of every finite collection of $A_i$'s is non-empty, then $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\neq\varnothing$.

So it suffices to see that for every finite collection of $I_n$'s, they have a non-empty intersection. But that's easy because the intersection of $I_{i_1}\cap\ldots\cap I_{i_n}$ is just $I_k$ for $k=\max\{i_j\mid j\leq n\}$. Since $I_k$ is non-empty, we have the wanted property.

By compactness we have that $\bigcap I_n\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: "we are in a compact space": Here you are appealing to Heine-Borel?

Comment: No, I'm appealing to the addendum, which says we can either know that the sets are compact, or closed and bounded. I just happened to know that compact sets are closed (forget about bounded).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = I_1$, which is compact.

Let $U_n = I_1-I_n $. The $U_n$ are open and nested. Suppose $\displaystyle \cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is empty. Then the $U_n$ cover $I_1$, so by compactness, there exists a finite subcover $U_{n_j}$. Then $$\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^mI_1 -I_{n_j} =I_1,$$ so  $$\bigcap_{j=1}^mI_{n_j}=I_{n_m}=\emptyset$$ - a contradiction